# function javascript plus and minus

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making plus and minus changing in javascript
The problem is the plus function just ran once but minus function is fine.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://athena3140.ml/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="container">
      <!--first-->
      <div class="inner" onclick="leftm()">
        <div class="minus">
          <div>&#8722;</div>
        </div>
        <div onclick="left()">
          <div class="mf" id="left">0</div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <script>
      let x = document.getElementById("left").innerHTML;
      
      function left() {
        document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = x++;
      }
      function leftm() {
        document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = x--;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are attempting to do. Please add context, and expected results.

Comment: You have some weird html structure going on. Like, you have an outer div that always calls `leftm()` on click. Nested inside of that you have a div with the minus sign html entity (it doesn't have an onclickk it just uses the parents). Also inside of it you have a button with an onclick of `left()` (it doesn't display a plus sign by the way, it displays the number).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- The first `onclick` is on an element that has *both* the minus and the number, so when you click on the number, this container element will *also* receive that event and call a function that counters the effect. The solution is to move that `onclick` attribute to the smaller container that only wraps around the minus.
- `x--` will still return the value of `x` without subtraction. That actual assignment to `x` of the decremented value happens *after* that evaluation. Same for `x++`. So use prefix notation instead.

```js
let x = document.getElementById("left").innerHTML;

function left() {
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = ++x;
}
function leftm() {
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = --x;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://athena3140.ml/style.css">
<div id="container" class="container">
  <!--first-->
  <div class="inner" >
    <div class="minus" onclick="leftm()">
      <div>&#8722;</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="left()">
      <div class="mf" id="left">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current markup is very confusing.

If you want to be able to both increment and decrement the value, each of the buttons need to exist as separate concepts. It would also help if they were siblings.

To simplify your markup, you should have a container that holds a decrement button, a value for display, and an increment button.

Adding (or subtracting) 1 from the display value can be performed in a utility function that takes the current `innerText`, parses it, adds a value, and then sets the `innerText` on the element.

```js
const valueEl = document.querySelector('.value');

const addValue = (el, value) =>
  el.innerText = parseInt(el.innerText, 10) + value;

const increment = () => addValue(valueEl, 1);
const decrement = () => addValue(valueEl, -1);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }
body { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
.container { display: flex; gap: 1rem; align-items: center; }
.action { display: flex; width: 2rem; height: 2rem; align-items: center; justify-content: center; cursor: pointer; border: thin solid grey; }
.decrement:after { content: '\2212'; }
.increment:after { content: '\002B'; }
.value { font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="action decrement" onClick="decrement()"></div>
  <div class="value">0</div>
  <div class="action increment" onClick="increment()"></div>
</div>
```